# java my array runs with for loops, but nothing displays?

Tags: java

I don't understand why this runs but does not print anything. (I am new to coding altogether, so any advice is great.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class ArrayDoubleValues{ 
  public static void main(String[] args){ 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Length input
    System.out.println("Length: ");
    int length = scan.nextInt();

    int[] list = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i == list.length; i++){
      list[i] =(int)(Math.random()+ 1) * 100; 
      System.out.print(list.length);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i == list.length; i++){
       System.out.println(list[i]); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's Java, not JavaScript :)

Comment: It isn't JavaScript, it's Java (I guess, maybe is just a mix of Java and JS). [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong condition here --

```
for (int i = 0; i == list.length; i++){
```

Your program never enters these loops because `i` is not equal to `list.length` when you reach them. Instead, it should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { ... }
```

Comment: this fixed it. Thank you!  I am confused though. Why would == not be accepted? Does it not mean "equal to" So it would stop when i equals the length of the array?

Comment: This condition means "repeat the loop _while_ it's true". Since it's never true, you repeat the loop 0 times.

Comment: I think you got it wrong how the loop statement works. The condition you define there must be met to enter the loop. If you put "i == list.length" in there that would mean you want it to execute only when i is equal to length of the list. However, whenever the condition isn't met the program will leave the for loop, won't increment i and will never go inside the loop (unless list.length is equal 0).